# How to hit a breakpoint using an cURL request

Tags: php, debugging, curl, breakpoints

does anybody know, if possible,
how I can send cURL requests and hit a breakpoint.

I tried with PHP 5.3 and Zend debugger and
xdebug.

Anyway I didn't get it working, the breakpoint 
is ignored.

Best regards

Comment: curl has nothing to do with breakpoints. you'd have to make sure that whatever curl requests causes the php script to go through the code path that contains the breakpoint.

Comment: Why do you need a breakpoint ?

Comment: I need to set breakpoints gernally for debugging :-)

When I call the same URL the cURL script did via browser I hit the breakpoint, why not when I run the a cURL request.

Comment: did u get the solution?